# Emit event for laravel echo with socket.io

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, socket.io, laravel-blade

I'm trying to implement a real-time whiteboard like this https://socket.io/demos/whiteboard/ with laravel echo on a presence channel. The problem is, how do I emit an event when another user is drawing because in the example it uses *socket.emit('drawing;,...)*. I know that the event should be triggered in the controller but I'm not too sure if sending the event via http(ajax) is a good idea because everytime someone draws, a http request will be sent. Is there a workaround here? or I'm missing something.

**Index.blade.php**

```
Echo.join(`consultation`)
    .listen('drawing',(e)=>{
        onDrawingEvent(e)
    })

var socket = io(window.location.hostname + ':6001');

window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);
onResize();

function drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1, color, emit){
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x0, y0);
    context.lineTo(x1, y1);
    context.strokeStyle = color;
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();

    if (!emit) { return; }
    var w = canvas.width;
    var h = canvas.height;

    socket.emit('drawing', {
    x0: x0 / w,
    y0: y0 / h,
    x1: x1 / w,
    y1: y1 / h,
    color: color
    });
    console.log(1);
}

function onDrawingEvent(data){
    console.log(2);
    var w = canvas.width;
    var h = canvas.height;
    drawLine(data.x0 * w, data.y0 * h, data.x1 * w, data.y1 * h, data.color);
}
```

**Channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('consultation', function ($user) {
   return $user;
});
```

Comment: `Broadcast::channel('consultation'` it should return Boolean not $user objcet

Comment: you can look at this https://webrtc.org/getting-started/data-channels

Comment: The docs says for presence channel it should return something like a user data not boolean. Boolean is for private channel. Plus the channel is working. I've tested it already @KamleshPaul